# How to connect Spark with Elastic Search

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

Hi so I have been trying to connect Spark with Elastic Search and I see that I need to use hadoop to do so. How exactly do I go about this? I have Spark and Elastic search hadoop installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page will explain it all https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html